# Spring Boot - Doctor-Patient relation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to create application to manage `Doctor-Patient` relations. `Patient` should be able to add `Medicine` information. We can assign `Doctor` to `Patient` and `Patient` to `Doctor`. I implemented `a)` case described below, but i have some problems creating `Security` for signing in.

My ideas:

a) One table for `Doctor` and another for `Patient`, connect them with `@ManyToMany`. But the question is how to manage `Security` (Login/Register) in this case? Use different endpoints?

##### Doctor.java

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class Doctor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    // Some @ManyToMany, but problem with security
}
```

##### Patient.java

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Medicine> medicineList = new ArrayList<>();

    // @ManyToMany with Doctor

    public void addDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
        // connect
    }

    public void addMedicine(Medicine medicine) {
        // add medicine class
    }

}
```

b) One table `User` with roles. But there is another problem that in this case table `User` for type `Doctor` will have many null fields (e.g. mentionted `Medicines`) and i need controller for that to serve only for user type `Patient`. Another question how to implement Service for that? Can i create `PatientService` and `DoctorService`, that each manage users with predefined type?

##### User.java

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "MYUSERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    // Some role management
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private RoleType roleType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Medicine> medicineList = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<User> doctorList = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "doctorList")
    private Set<User> patientList = new HashSet<>();

    public void addPatient(User patient) {
        patientList.add(patient);
        patient.doctorList.add(this);
    }

    public void addDoctor(User doctor) {
        doctorList.add(doctor);
        doctor.patientList.add(doctor);
    }

    public void addMedicine(Medicine medicine) {
        // add medicine class (ONLY FOR PATIENT)
    }

}
```

Which of the two solutions is better?

Comment: to implement security you'll need to pass your user service class (a single class) to the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService` method, so having 2 service classes isn't going to work. While it's unusual for an application of this kind to be used by both doctors and patients, it can certainly be done by assigning different roles to users of different types. The downside is that your entity class (User) and the corresponding database table won't be optimally used (null values as you mentioned) and the business logic could be more complex given different user types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my pov both doctors and patients are `Users` so it would be easier to extract the common code to a user class as you did in option B but not entirely.

```
class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private UserType type; // DOCTOR / PATIENT
} 

class Doctor {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
    name = "doctor_pacients", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pactient_id"))
    Set<Patients> pacients;
}

class Patient {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
    name = "pactients_medicines", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pacient_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "medicine_id"))
    Set<Medicine> medicines;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "pacients", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Doctor> doctors;
}


class Medicine {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "medicines", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Patient> patients;
}
```

Now, for the permissions part we need we can use the `userType` to fetch the right entity and do some logic

Edit: But there is a case where a doctor can also be a patient but given we have a relationship of both Doctor/Patient with the User entity, we can try and ask both tables (Doctors/Patients) and depending on the context, we given them the OK or not to do a certain operation